# What is a word or phrase that describes both pain and vindication of having correctly predicted something bad?

Tags: phrase-requests

If someone predicts that a course of action will have bad consequences, but isn't believed by anyone at the time, and later those consequences occur, that person can feel vindicated and say "I told you so", but wish they hadn't been right because of the bad consequences. Is there a word or phrase to describe this feeling?

Comment: Certainly the myth of Cassandra, in all its versions, has this idea embedded in it, because she foresaw the fall of Troy.

Comment: Grim satisfaction?

Comment: *a feeling of [disrepute](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/disrepute)*: "the state of not being trusted or respected" - Happens to me almost daily, so I just call it normal. But I never say I told you so; you have to learn that for yourself.

Comment: Why would it not be sufficient to say 'I'm so sorry that I told you so'?